# Multiple Condition Daily Counts by Month/Year in Pandas DF

Tags: pandas, events, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, multiple-conditions

I have hourly data in a dataframe (df) and I need to count days that meet multiple data column conditions and then sum these counts by month and year in the df to describe a daily "event" where all 3 data conditions exist. My data looks like this:

```
   site        wind           time                 temp          rh        year   month day
0  Cirrus         4.3        2011-01-01 20:00:00        5.9       54.6         2011    1     1 
1  Cirrus         3.9        2011-01-01 19:00:00        4.2       28.5         2011    1     1
2  Cirrus         6.8        2011-01-01 18:00:00        3.3       19.5         2011    1     1
3  Stratus        4.9        2011-01-01 23:00:00        2.9       27.3         2011    1     1
4  Stratus        2.9        2011-01-01 22:00:00        1.8       17.1         2011    1     1
5  Stratus        2.1        2011-01-01 21:00:00        0.2       53.2         2011    1     1
6  Stratus        0.9        2014-02-01 23:00:00        3.8       19.9         2014    2     1
```

My criteria needs to be for 3 conditions: wind (<=5), temp (>=1.0 and <= 5.0), rh (<= 30).

My result should look like this:

```
    Site       year  month   condition_count
0   Cirrus     2011  1       1
1   Stratus    2011  1       2
2   Stratus    2014  2       1
```

I've looked at using lambda functions to filter by rows for each column threshold something like this but I'm not sure it's a good direction to obtain the answer.

```
isWind = lambda x:int(x <= 5)
isAir = lambda x:int(x >= 1 & <=5)
isRH = lambda x:int(x <=30)
countlimits = lambda row: isWind(row['wind_speed_ms']) + isAir(row['air_temp_c']) + 
isRH(row['relative_humidity_pct'])

df['Event_Days'] = df.apply(countlimits,axis=1)
```

I've also tried something like this but it gives an error of mixing rand array with a scalar:

```
df_final = df[(df.wind_speed_ms < 5) & (df.loc[(df['air_temp_c'] >= 1) 
& (df['air_temp_c'] < 5)]) & (df.relative_humidity_pct <= 30)].sum()
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: df[(df['wind']>=5)&(df['temp']>=1)&(df['temp']<=5)&(df['rh']<=30)]   or you can put a similar syntax into a string and use df,query

Answer (score 1):

```
df_final = df[(df['wind_speed_ms']<=5) & (df['air_temp_c']>=1) & (df['air_temp_c']<=5) & (df['relative_humidity_pct']<=30)].groupby(['Site','year','month']).day.nunique().reset_index()

df_final.columns = ['Site','year','month','event_days']
```